# How to generate a random double value in a specific range using Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, random

How do I generate a random number in a specific float range (From 51.3257 to 52.4557 for example) using Kotlin?

```
var xCoord = randomValue()
var yCoord = randomValue()
```

Do I need to make a method or do I just import something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
double random = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(51.3257, 52.4557);
```

Comment: I need the floating point values to at least 4 decimals, preferably 7

Comment: says the range is empty: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Random range is empty: [51.6193633, 51.6189061).

Answer (score 13):

Here is the documentation for that: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.random/-random/index.html

I believe that it would be something like

```
import kotlin.random.Random

var xCoord = Random.nextDouble(51.3257, 52.4557)
var xCoord = Random.nextDouble(51.3257, 52.4557)
```

Comment: I am getting a 'Cannot create an instance of an abstract class' error

Answer (score 0):

If you are using kotlin do this :

```
 var max=51.3257
 var min=52.4557
 var outpot= (min + Random.nextDouble() * (max - min))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Random r = new Random();
double randomValue = rangeMin + (rangeMax - rangeMin) * r.nextDouble();
```

Please try this. Thanks